# R simple sub setting with NA

Tags: r

```
x <- data.frame("va1" =sample(1:5), "var2" = sample(6:10), "var3"=sample(11:15))
```

Above line will create a three column each has 5 rows.

```
x <- x[sample(1:5),]; x$var3[c(1,3)]=NA
```

Using above code, I randomized the numbers of all three columns and added few NA's in column var3

```
x[(x$var3==NA),]
```

Using this code i was expecting to get the all the values where column var3 = NA instead I got five row and three columns of all NA's. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
x[is.na(x$var3), ]
#   va1 var2 var3
# 2   5   10   NA
# 1   1    6   NA
```

because `NA` values are "special". The same applies to NaN, not finite values; see `?is.finite`, `?is.infinite`, `?is.nan`.

Comment: Thank you Julius. That helped

Comment: @XXavier, no problem. Welcome to SO; I suggest you to check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to use

```
x[(x$var3 %in% NA),]
```

this two minute video explains the difference between == and %in% really nicely
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hx4A4LUgzQc

Goodluck

Comment: Did you look on the other answer too? How is that different/better?

Comment: Using the %in% operator is absolutely different than using is.na() - both work - obviously it is helpful to know both options depending on your application.  Hopefully the difference between %in% and == help explains why his/her approach wasn't working.